# Como gerenciar múltiplas transações com o FireDAC?

Tags: delphi

Saudações.

Tenho um TFDConnection e gostaria de ter dois TFDTransactions no meu projeto.
O TFDConnection não está ligado a nenhum Transaction, apenas os Transactions estão ligados no Connection. Apenas a TFDQuery está ligada no Connection e também num dos Transactions.
Após ser dado um UPDATE com a FDQuery e um COMMIT no Transaction a informação não é commitada no banco.
Agora a pergunta: POR QUE?

Detalhes:

- Banco: FireBird;
- IDE: Delphi XE7;
- Obs: Antes do UPDATE dou um StartTransaction no TFDTransaction e no
  final, um COMMIT.

Grato.

Comment: Teoricamente, o que você disse está correto. Teria como postar algo do seu código para conferirmos?

Answer (score 1):

Seria interessante você postar o código para te auxiliarmos.

Mas você pode ver a seguinte situação:

**1** - Se não "commitou", pode ser que o Update não funcionou.

**2** - E Quando usar Transaction, use essa estrutura para não ter problemas.

```
FDTransaction.StartTransaction;
Try
  // sua rotina
  FDTransaction.Commit;
Except
  FDTransaction.Rollback;
end;
```